# numpy AttributeError: with theano module 'numpy.core.multiarray' has no attribute _get_ndarray_c_version

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I'm running this simple example:

```
import theano
x = theano.tensor.dscalar()
f = theano.function([x], 2*x)
f(4)
```

and I get:

```
AttributeError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}(TensorConstant{2.0}, <TensorType(float64, scalar)>), '\n', "module 'numpy.core.multiarray' has no attribute '_get_ndarray_c_version'")
```

I though it must be a numpy error, so I try to update but I have the latest version as far as I know:

```
import numpy

numpy.version.version
'1.16.2'
```

I'm running all this in spyder but that seems to be irrelevant since I get the same error in python interpreter

Comment: you need to downgrade the numpy version to the 1.16.0 (have you upgrade or install any library before having this error for the first time?)

Answer (score 10):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/6671) presumably caused by [changes introduced in NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/31df302656b88df2937c5ac338c96b1a0ec6d687).  A fix for this was introduced in Theano v1.0.4. So, either you need to upgrade to at least that version of Theano, or downgrade NumPy to below v1.16.

Note that at the moment (25 July 2019) only Conda Forge has Theano v1.0.4, whereas Anaconda has v1.0.3.  So you need to run

```
conda install -c conda-forge theano=1.0.4
```

Otherwise, the NumPy downgrade is

```
conda install numpy=1.15
```

Comment: I'm using Anaconda and when I go to update theano, it's still the v.1.0.3.  How do I downgrade NumPy?

Comment: @DataGirl sorry for the delayed response. I've updated the answer with explicit instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the

> Anaconda3\pkgs\theano-1.0.3-py37_0\Lib\site-packages\theano\gof

**open** `cc.py`

go to **line 1376**

comment these code:

```
sig.append('NPY_ABI_VERSION=0x%X' %
        np.core.multiarray._get_ndarray_c_version())
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trpW1.png)

For more details you can **Refer**:

https://github.com/MichalDanielDobrzanski/DeepLearningPython35/issues/20

https://www.wandouip.com/t5i268914/

Comment: Well, if you're going to go as far as editing the source (not recommended since it violates the reproduciblity of the env), I'd at least encourage you to change it to match [the actual patch that was done](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/commit/5953f2d6e4a305852fa6e3f3ae28da2a40cdaf41).